# Race condition in my AJAX code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coldfusion

Using Coldfusion 10 and jQuery to dynamically populate a select, based on the value of another select. I've set the AJAX to be synchronous, so that it doesn't try to populate the select until the AJAX request is complete. However, every once in a while a user sees the select without any options, which suggests to me there's a race condition in spite of the synchronous setting. Is there anything in my code below that would be causing a race condition?

```
    function fChangeTxOutcome(sel) {
                /* function receives controlling select as an argument */
                /* there are actually 2 sets of controller/controllee selects, so vars below identify which select should be populated, based on controller select's id */
                var encCatIdList = '';
                var id = sel.prop('id');
                var idNum = id[id.length-1];
                var txOutcomeDiv = $('##htreat' + idNum);
                var txOutcomeSelect = document.getElementById('txOutcomeSelect' + idNum);
                /* encCatIdList will be passed to a Coldfusion function/query via AJAX, to get the correct set of options */
                if (sel.val() != '9' && sel.val() != '714') {
                    txOutcomeDiv.show();
                    encCatIdList = '8,11';
                }
                else if (sel.val() == '9') {
                    txOutcomeDiv.show();
                    encCatIdList = '9';
                }
                else if (sel.val() == '714') {
                    txOutcomeDiv.hide();
                    encCatIdList = '0';
                }
/* assessment.cfc is essentially an object. getEncCatChildrenRemote is the function, and encCatIdList is an argument passed to it */
                $.ajax({
                    url: "#request.webroot#cfc/assessment.cfc?method=getEncCatChildrenRemote&encCatIdList=" + encCatIdList,
                    success: function (jsonText) {
                        var qryTxOutcomes = JSON.parse(jsonText);

                        //qryTxOutcomes is now an object with 2 arrays: COLUMNS and DATA.
                        //COLUMNS is an array of strings of the column names.
                        //DATA is an array of arrays, where each array is a row.
                        //Thus, every data cell is DATA[rownumber][columnnumber]
                        //[0] = cEncOutcomeId
                        //[1] = cEncCatId
                        //[2] = bTreatProgActive
                        //[3] = encOutcomeName
                        //[4] = encCatId
                        //[5] = iCodedecodeId
                        //[6] = encCatName

                        //clear out any options in the selectfirst
                        for(var i=txOutcomeSelect.options.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
                            txOutcomeSelect.remove(i);
                        }

                        var firstOption = document.createElement('option');
                        firstOption.setAttribute('value', '');
                        firstOption.innerHTML = '--Select an Option--';
                        txOutcomeSelect.appendChild(firstOption);

                        /* this is where the select is populated. At this point there should be a JSON object returned from the AJAX call, but it appears that occassionally the below code is running before the AJAX call is complete, so the select ends up getting populated with nothing */
                        $.each(qryTxOutcomes.DATA, function() {
                            var thisOption = document.createElement('option');
                            thisOption.setAttribute('value', $(this)[5]);
                            thisOption.innerHTML = $(this)[3];
                            txOutcomeSelect.appendChild(thisOption);
                        });
                    },
                    async: false
                });
            }// end fChangeTxOutcome()
```

Comment: Firstly, please remove `async: false`. I know you were only testing it, but it's not a workable solution, even if it did fix your issue. I assume you're only making one request at a time, if so then the problem cannot be a race condition. If the problem is intermittent then I'd suggest it's a server issue, either due to timeout, excess load or rate restrictions. The next time you see the behaviour try checking the console and network tab to see what the actual failure reason was given for the request

Comment: But I don't see why the code would just go ahead and try to populate the select before the request has returned the JSON string, given how I've coded it, even if the server is lagging. Unless, it's not even getting to the  "each" loop, or anywhere inside the success block for that matter, because the "success" event never happens...

Comment: @Cmaso I don't see any race conditions. My best guess is that the connection is failing sometimes. Try adding a error handler to the ajax call.

Comment: Could also be something in your javascript failing before the call is even made for example it's possible an element on page doesn't exist when the function above is called which is easily fixed by wrapping in a $(document).ready call but without seeing the whole html you cant really tell